# Do I need to place `endif` beneath each `if` Conditional Statement or can they be grouped together at the bottom of entire Blog Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have just inserted the following code into a page template:

```
<?php   
//First Loop    
    $testBlog = new WP_Query(
        'type=post&posts_per_page=1' 
    );  

        if ( $testBlog->have_posts() ):
            while( $testBlog->have_posts() ): $testBlog->the_post(); 
                get_template_part('format',get_post_format());      
            endwhile; 
            wp_reset_postdata();

    //Second Loop
        $newTestBlog = new WP_Query(
            'type=post&posts_per_page=3&offset=0'
        );

            if ( $newTestBlog ->have_posts() ):
                while( $newTestBlog ->have_posts() ): $newTestBlog ->the_post(); 
                    get_template_part('format',get_post_format());      
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;  

        endif;
?>
```

Is it okay to end the above code with 2 `endif`s, as there are 2 `if` Conditional Statements or do the `endif`s need to be placed directly beneath its associated Conditional Statement before the next Conditional Statement is run?

Also, I have placed `testBlog` and `newTestBlog` into the code as I am under the impression they need to be unqiue.  Is this the case or can they be duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you use `if (expression):` you need also end `endif;` **always**. It is the equivalent to an `{` that you have to close as well with `}`.

But the `endif;` syntax should primary used in context with HTML code not in PHP only code:

```
<?php if ($header == true): ?>
    <h1>Header</h1>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>paragraph</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you have PHP only code use this:

```
 if ($header == true) {
     // it's true
 }
 else {
     // it's false
 }
```

The same it true for `while (expression):` and `endwhile;` etc.

See [PHP PSR-2: Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2)

Here how you code would look like:

```
<?php

$testBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1');

if ($testBlog->have_posts()) {

    while ($testBlog->have_posts()) {

        $testBlog->the_post();
        get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $newTestBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=3&offset=0');

    if ($newTestBlog->have_posts()) {

        while ($newTestBlog->have_posts()) {

            $newTestBlog->the_post();
            get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

If you say now: *this is not what I want*, because you want to do 2 independent blocks, than you understand why this it's a better way, because you see your mistakes immediately. I assume you want to do this:

```
<?php

$testBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1');

if ($testBlog->have_posts()) {

    while ($testBlog->have_posts()) {

        $testBlog->the_post();
        get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}

$newTestBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=3&offset=0');

if ($newTestBlog->have_posts()) {

    while ($newTestBlog->have_posts()) {

        $newTestBlog->the_post();
        get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: "But the endif; syntax should primary used in context with HTML code not in PHP only code" why?

Comment: There is no technical reason, but the code is much more readable and such question would not rise. This is why it is considered good developer practice. See Update

Comment: Well, it's a matter of opinion. I was asking about the "should" in there. PSR-2 seems to have nothing on the matter?

Comment: My first sentence is you awnser, the rest is as you call it official PHP developer community opinion

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fine to use two endifs. Each endif will correspond to the first if conditional above it that it encounters, that has not been closed by another endif.